# Allocating house with 2 coordinates in Leaflet.GeoJSON?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have 2 coordinates of the house.

Is it possible to allocate this house with other color in Leaflet?

Is it possible using GeoJSON?

Or need to draw a polygon?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.